# Unable to load DLL(OIDv4_ToolKit)

Tags: dll

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghdcn.png)

This problem has been troubling me for a whole day. I have tried all the methods I know, but still can't solve it. Just to let you know, I'm a beginner in programming, and there are many things I don't understand. Please forgive me for that.

Thanks for your help.